# Javascript: Should an argument passed to a function be defined as 'let', 'const' or 'var'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants, var, let

Consider the following code snippet:

```
// Set 'token' to have string value or null

if ("nextForwardToken" in event.queryStringParameters) {
  var token = event.queryStringParameters.nextForwardToken;
} else {
  var token = null;
}

getData(token, callback);
```

The `token` parameter for the function `getData` may either be null or a string.

The code block on the caller side defines the variable token and sets it to the right value.

What's the right way to quantify the `token` variable on the caller side? Should it be `let`, `const` or `var`?

Comment: Did you try what happens when you replace `var` in that code with either `let` or `const`?

Comment: Sure, including the ternary operator. Just wanted to know if there's an idiomatic JS way to declare an argument, set its value conditionally, and pass it to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing.

You are asking about the "caller" side, but the side of the code that is calling the `getData()` function clearly defines the `token` variable as `var` already right there in your code.  You could use `let` if you wanted to narrow the scope to block scope if you defined `let token` before the `if` statement.  You can't use `let` in place of `var` in your code because that would define the variable only within your `if` block, but you want to use it outside that block.

**Using let:**

So, you could use `let` like this:

```
let token;
if ("nextForwardToken" in event.queryStringParameters) {
  token = event.queryStringParameters.nextForwardToken;
} else {
  token = null;
}
getData(token, callback);
```

If this was not already at the top level function scope, then using `let` would narrow the scope to just the parent block.

**Using const:**

You can't really use this structure with `const` because `const` can only be defined once and must contain an initializer.  So, if you wanted to use `const`, then you could do this:

```
const token = "nextForwardToken" in event.queryStringParameters ? event.queryStringParameters.nextForwardToken : null;
getData(token, callback);
```

Of course, you could even do this without the temporary variable at all:

```
getData("nextForwardToken" in event.queryStringParameters ? event.queryStringParameters.nextForwardToken : null, callback);
```

---

**Inside of getData():**

How you define (`const`, `let` or `var`) whatever you pass to `getData()` has no effect at all on how the function argument works inside of `getData()`.  So, if your question was really about that, then it doesn't matter inside of `getData()`.  Function arguments in both ES5 and ES6 are always mutable (like `var` or `let`) and that is not something that is currently changeable in the language.  They are separate variables that are assigned the values you passed them, thus they don't inherit any `const` attributes from what you passed and their scope is defined by the new function definition so their scope has nothing to do with whether the passed variable was `const`, `let` or `var`.

So, if you have your `getData()` function declared as:

```
function getData(theToken) {

}
```

Then, `theToken` is a mutable argument and there is no way to make it `const`.  Since it is essentially declared at the top level of the function, there would really be no difference between `var` and `let` so it doesn't really matter between those as the scope is already the whole function and it's already essentially hoisted.

---

In ES6, there are interesting work-around possible such as this:

```
function getData() {
    const [theToken] = arguments;

    // access theToken here as const

}
```

One could still override that by accessing `arguments[0]` directly, but that would certainly have to be intentional, not accidental.

> What's the right way to quantify the token variable on the caller side? Should it be let, const or  var?

It's like either `var` or `let`.  Since it's at the top scope of the function and already hoisted, there really is no difference.  If you mentally want to pick one, then say it's like `var` since it is always function scoped.

Comment: Excellent profound answer, thanks a lot. Does the way I use var make sense, or should I declare the variable first and then assign? Any idiomatic JS recommendation?

Comment: @AdamMatan - It's generally not good to repeat a `var` definition.  While JS allows it, it tends to lead someone reading your code to think you are declaring a new variable (when in fact, it may already exist) and it implies block scoping (though `var` is function scoped).  So, better to put `var token` before the `if` statement and just assign the variable (the same way I did in my `let` example).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: What about assignment without a quantifier? Simply `token =`?

Comment: @AdamMatan - Never assign to a variable that has not been declared.  That creates an implicit global which is really bad coding style that can lead to programming accidents.  The most common one is to refer to `i` in a `for` loop without any declaration and then you wonder why a function your `for` loop breaks when you call a function from it (that also does the same thing and they trounce each other's use of `i`).  So, always explicitly declare it `var`, `const` or `let`.  And, even better, run in strict mode where it's an error if you assign to a variable without declaring it first.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `var`, using `let` and `const` will make the variable block scope and only exists in the `if` block. Using `const` is also unessessary excepts you would use it and would not change it in the future.

Comment: And `const` suffers from the same scoping issue as `let`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't write your code simply like this:

```
// Set 'token' to have string value or null
let token = null;
if ("nextForwardToken" in event.queryStringParameters) {
  token = event.queryStringParameters.nextForwardToken;
}

getData(token, callback);
```